# Problema al modificar campos de un tabla (No almacena)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Saludos, tengo un problema con el siguiente codigo, tras probar me he dado cuenta de que algo esta sucediendo con mis variables que al colocarlas me deja de actualizar los datos, me explico:

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me funciona perfecto:

```html
if ($boton == "Modificar"){
 if ($cedula!=""){
  $sql="update datosbasicos set CED_PAC=$cedula, NOM_PAC='$nombre', APE_PAC='$apellido',EDAD_PAC='$edad', HIS_PAC='$nhistoria', DIR_PAC='$direccion', TEL_PAC='$telefono', CEL_PAC='$celular', SEX_PAC ='$sexo' where CED_PAC='$cedula'";
  mysql_query($sql);
  echo "<script>alert('Datos modificados correctamente')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.location='registro.php'</script>";
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>alert('Para poder modificadar debe realizar una busqueda')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.location='registro.php'</script>";
 }
}
```

Ahora bien, necesito modificar ese codigo y agregarle las siguientes variables para que me modifique diferentes campos de otra tabla, quedaria así:

```html
if ($boton == "Modificar"){
 if ($cedula!=""){
  $sql="UPDATE datosmedicos SET COD_CONSULTA='$codigo', ALT_PAC= '$altura', PESO_PAC='$peso', FECHA='$fecha', TIPO_CONSULTA='$tipconsulta', SINTOMAS='$sintomas', OBSERV='$observacion', HIS_PAC='$nhistoria', MEDI_PAC='$medicamentos', OPERADO='$operado', ALERGIAS='$alergias' where CED_PAC='$cedula'";
  mysql_query($sql);
  echo "<script>alert('Datos modificados correctamente')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.location='consulta.php'</script>";
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>alert('Para poder modificadar debe realizar una busqueda')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.location='consulta.php'</script>";
 }
}
```

Este codigo ya no me sirve, desde el momento en que coloco la primera variable me deja de funcionar, a pesar de que me dice que se ha almacenado correctamente no sucede ningun cambio.

No creo que sea por no estar trabajando con MySQLi como me dijeron una vez por allí, pues entonces no estaria funcionando el primer codigo, he verificado la base de datos y los campos son correctos ¿A Alguien se le ocurre alguna respuesta?

Muchas gracias.

**EDIT**

Muestro como tengo declaradas las variables por si alguien quiere ver:

```
    <?php  

include('conexion.php');
$boton = $_POST["boton"];
$cedula = $_POST["CED_PAC"];
$nombre = $_POST["NOM_PAC"];
$apellido = $_POST["APE_PAC"];
$edad = $_POST["EDAD_PAC"];
$nhistoria = $_POST["HIS_PAC"];
$direccion = $_POST["DIR_PAC"];
$telefono = $_POST["TEL_PAC"];
$celular = $_POST["CEL_PAC"];
$sexo = $_POST["SEX_PAC"];
$codigo = $_POST["COD_CONSULTA"];
$fecha = $_POST["FECHA"];
$tipconsulta = $_POST["TIPO_CONSULTA"];
$observacion = $_POST["OBSERV"];
$sintomas = $_POST["SINTOMAS"];
$peso = $_POST["PESO_PAC"];
$altura = $_POST["ALT_PAC"];
$operado = $_POST["OPERADO"];
$alergias = $_POST["ALERGIAS"];
$medicamentos = $_POST["MEDI_PAC"];
```

**BASE DE DATOS**

Tengo la base de datos de la siguiente manera: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Los querys son distintos, a eso te refieres con variables?

Comment: Así es Gbianchi, los datos que solicito son distintos y he ahi donde recide el problema, pues al solicitar los del segundo codigo no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Hola **Pablo Pernia**,

según lo que indicas, si el código que ejecutas primero si te modificó correctamente los datos y ya el segundo no, el error puede estar en que las nuevas variables que estás enviando estén definidas en tu base de datos como datos tipo entero y la estás enviando como tipo string.

Verifica lo siguiente:

Que el orden de variables del query sea igual al orden de variables en tu base de datos. 
  **Ejemplo:**  Si en tu base de datos está Cedula(INT), Nombre(Varchar), Apellido(Varchar). Entonces enviar en el query `UPDATE datosbasicos SET Cedula=$Cedula, Nombre='$Nombre', Apellido='$Apellido' WHERE Cedula=$Cedula.`

Como se ve en el ejemplo que te hice, en este caso Cedula esta como entero, entonces la envio sin comillas y Nombre y Apellido están como Varchar entonces los envío tipo String encerrándolo entre comillas.

**Para tener en cuenta:**

Es poco recomendable que un registro único como la Cédula se pueda modificar, lo recomendable es realizar la búsqueda por la Cédula y modificar el resto de datos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Henry, efectivamente estaba enviando la cedula e historia del paciente como string y era INT, mas sin embargo al hacer el ajuste persiste el problema, editare en el post principal como lo tengo ahora, para ver que se puede hacer e intentare mostrar mi base de datos para que comparen los resultados. @henry

Comment: Ya actualice arriba de como lo tengo, revisa @Henry

Comment: No se habia actualizado bien, ahora si, revisa y disculpa.

Comment: HIS_PAC='$nhistoria' estás enviandolo como String y en la bd lo tienes INT. Según veo en la imagen, además revisa si tienes relacionada la PK con otra tabla ya que la estás editando también.

Comment: Cuando te refieres a la PK ¿A que te refieres? ya modifique en mi codigo el de HIS_PAC=$nhistoria y aún nada que me acepta la modificacion.

Comment: PK (Principal Key) en tu caso COD_CONSULTA, si tienes relacionada la principal key en otra tabla y tienes un registro relacionado con esa PK, te va a dar conflicto modificarla. Quita lo de modificar la PK para ver. Además veo que antes la sentencia la hacías con la tabla datosbasicos   y ahora con la tabla datosmedicos , revisa eso también.

Comment: Verifique y no, no la tengo como PK en ninguna otra tabla, la quite para probar y aun sigue el problema, si es que te explico cambia de **datosbasicos** a **datosmedicos** porque la de datosbasicos es tal cual, registro los datos basicos del paciente y luego paso a datos medicos que es otra pagina.

Comment: ¿Que ha sido de esto, lograste solucionarlo?